# Is there any possible way to display a H.264 RTSP stream with Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Since Google Chrome disallowed the use of NPAPI plugins and Chrome doesn't support RTSP in the HTML5 player, it has become rather challenging to find a method of viewing RTSP live streams.

So now I'm looking for pretty much anything that will get the job done, the only real constraints: It needs to work in Google Chrome, and it needs to work on Linux.

I've seen a few questions which are similar, but they all either predate the discontinuation of plugins, or are unanswered.